# How to configure application name when running dev_appserver.py?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-app-engine-python

I used to configure the application name in app.yaml. But I just re-read the latest docs, and they say:

> The recommended approach is to remove the application element from your app.yaml file and instead, use a command-line flag to specify your application ID:
>
> To use the gcloud app deploy command, you must specify the --project flag:
>
> `gcloud app deploy --project [YOUR_PROJECT_ID]`
>
> To use the appcfg.py update command, you specify the -A flag:
>
> `appcfg.py update -A [YOUR_PROJECT_ID]`

But what about `dev_appserver.py`? How do I configure it with the project name?

Comment: `-A` works for me for the dev server - it overrides any value in app.yaml

Comment: Nice, thanks! Yeah I see now it's described by showing usage: `dev_appserver.py -h` If you put it as an answer, I'll mark it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`dev_appserver.py` also supports the `-A` flag to set the application id.

From the output for `dev_appserver.py -h`:

> -A APP_ID, --application APP_ID
>                           Set the application, overriding the application value
>                           from the app.yaml file. (default: None)